# Failed to mount automatically in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 14.04 Lts. And i have administrative access.
I have failed to mount the disk drivers automatically. It says

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda7: Command-line `mount "/mnt/D6EEAF55EEAF2D25"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I have used the disk drivers option to mount it. But It **gives error on startup and ask S for skip and M for manual mounting**.
[i have installed windows 8 and ubuntu in different drive.]

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/462381/cant-mount-ntfs-drive-the-disk-contains-an-unclean-file-system

Answer (score 6):

Try this in Terminal, I hope it works:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the solution. It is due to the windows 8 fast boot up feature. 
I have just disabled the fast boot option in windows 8 and it worked for me.

Here you can get how to disable fast boot feature in windows 8.
[enter link description here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/what-is-fast-startup-windows-8-disable-it/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this cmd tool, ntfsfix that worked for me 
`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` 
`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7`